# wait http req unit finish angular (services)

Tags: angular, service, subscribe

in my component angular call services I need to wait and change before move to execute all code any solution?

```
read(idPos:string){
  var choice = 0;   
  this.menuItemsService.getAllDataMenuItemsByParentId(idPos).subscribe(data=> 
    { 
    choice = 1; // change Value to 1 
    if(data.length !=0){
     this.data =data;
    }   

    console.log(choice)
  })
  console.log(choice); // print 0 no change to =1
```

Comment: You have to move all your code need to execute after the http call inside the subscribe callback. what's the confusion here?

Comment: subscribe callback will only fire after your observable http request complete

Comment: I need Know length data receive and make boolean change after that and call other services depend on that

Comment: You can do both the operations(setting boolean value and calling other services) inside the subscribe call back itself like @dexter had answered.  you can elaborate your question if the suggestions are not clear.

Comment: Thanks You! @NinjaJami

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you should not be putting any code below an asynchronous call (subscribe) as you have in your example.

Instead, consider this:

```
read(idPos:string){
  var choice = 0;   
  this.menuItemsService.getAllDataMenuItemsByParentId(idPos).subscribe(data=> 
  { 
    choice = 1; // change Value to 1 
    if(data.length !=0){
     this.data =data;
    }   

    console.log(choice)

    this.continueRead(choice);
  })
  // console.log(choice); // <<< remove this line.
}

continueRead(choice: number) {
  console.log(choice); // <<< will print 1
}
```

Comment: Thanks You! @dexter